# 404 error on a page that I am not calling

Tags: html, apache, redirect, http-status-code-404

I get this error when I hit submit on my html page. It has a textbox where I enter an id. I want it to redirect me to a jsp page named `Output`. Instead, it says `Success.html` not found!

```
HTTP Status 404 - /Success.html
type Status report    
message /Success.html
description The requested resource is not available.
```

My HTML Page has

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="Output" method="get">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron" align="center">
                <h1>Lab Test 1 : Student Information System</h1>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><h2>Student Name: Divya Rao &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</h2></td>
                        <td>
                            <h2>Roll No: MT2014032</h2>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <h1>Output Screen</h1>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><h4>Student Id</h4></td>
                    <td><h4>Marks</h4></td>
                    <td><h4>Picture</h4></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="id"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-success"        
                    ></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I searched for 'success' in my entire workspace but I don't seem to be calling it anywhere. What is happening?

Comment: can you put the full response up?

Comment: @vernak2539 I just edited my post. But the error I get is that.

Comment: try changing the input type to "submit" and then change the action to "/Output" and see if you get a different result. You may need an extension on the action also, depending on what language you're using

Comment: @vernak2539 I tried what you said, doesn't work. I have an input form which submits just fine. I do not know what is requesting the "Success.html" page. It doesn't exist!

Comment: What happens if you try navigating directly to the Output page? I suspect that is redirecting you to /Success.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried fixing this error all night. i didn't have the page it was redirecting to, nor had I referenced it. So it was exhausting.
A system reboot fixed it.